# How to make post a status update to a page as the Page itself and not as the user?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

https://graph.facebook.com/cencored/feed?message=test&access_token=cencored

That is what I'm currently doing.

It's working fine, but it's posting as the user, not as the page.

The Facebook doc isn't too clear about this:

> Once your app has a **Page access token** and the **right permissions**, it can have a Page post a status update. The update appears in the Page's timeline. Your app should make requests to graph.facebook.com.

I have `manage_pages, email, publish_pages, publish_actions` permissions in my access token.

So, what next? It's not that clear, at all.

So how can I make it post as a page?

Comment: the duplicate is about php, but the answer is the same and you will find a LOT more threads about that question on stackoverflow.

Comment: I did see that, but I understood nothing from the php.

Comment: why do you need publish_actions? all you need is publish_pages and a page token.

Comment: take a look at the answer in the duplicate thread, it´s generic and does not only apply to php

Comment: @luschn ok, so it's more than enough. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you are not using a page token, that is all. again, read the answer in that other thread.

Comment: @luschn ah, I thought you meant another thread. Ok, you're right, it is a duplicate. Was looking for that

Comment: @luschn It's working, but it's not public for some reason. I can see it, under "posts", but when I use another browser and i'm not logged in I can't. It works if I do it manually using the "write something" text box.

Comment: @luschn It's just not showing in the timeline. It's showing for me, but not publicly.

Comment: make the app public then. you really have to do some research before asking, this has been discussed a lot of times on stackoverflow already ;)

Comment: @luschn yes, I know, they say "you have to turn off sandbox mode". But I had no idea what sandbox mode was, it seems as if it was renamed, that's why I asked you. Thanks